# Right padding a String with Zeros in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I need to right pad this with leading zeros to a length of 3 in the output (which is fixed length text)

Examples:

A becomes A00

AB becomes AB0

ABC becomes ABC

Please help.

Comment: Please do not tag your question with all possible XSLT versions. Pick the highest version you can use. Also post a [mcve] showing input, your current XSLT and the expected output.

Comment: I think you mean trailing zeros, not leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do simply:

```
substring(concat($your-string, '000'), 1, 3)
```

Note that this means that `"ABCD"` becomes `"ABC"`.